# Efficiently computing pairwise KL divergence between multiple diagonal-covariance Gaussian distributions

Tags: normal-distribution, python, kullback-leibler

Let's say I want to compute the pairwise KL divergence between a large number (O(100)) of multivariate Gaussian distributions with diagonal covariance. The mean parameters for each Gaussian are stored within a matrix, where the rows correspond to the mean vectors, and the same applies for the diagonal of the covariance matrix of each Gaussian.

I could use a nested for loop to achieve this, but this seems slightly wasteful. Is there a more efficient way (preferably using `numpy` or something Pythonic), to return a matrix $D$ where the $(i,j)$-th entry $D_{ij} = D_{KL}\left(\mathcal{N}(\mu_i, \Sigma_i) \Vert \mathcal{N}(\mu_j, \Sigma_j)\right)$ corresponds to the KLD between distributions $i$ and $j$?

I know that it is possible to compute this efficiently for the case where we assume homoscedasticity $\Sigma_i = \sigma^2 \mathbb{1} \; \forall \; i$, as it is possible to calculate the form of the KL via a pairwise distance matrix, as in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2240429/pairwise-distance-matrix), but not sure how to generalize this to the Mahalanobis distance - looking term in the KLD term.

For reference, here is the KLD between two diagonal-covariance Gaussians of dimension $D$:

$$
D_{KL}\left(\mathcal{N}(\mu_i, \Sigma_i) \Vert \mathcal{N}(\mu_j, \Sigma_j)\right) = \frac{1}{2} \left[ Tr \log \Sigma_j - Tr\log \Sigma_i + (\mu_i - \mu_j)^T \Sigma_j^{-1} (\mu_i-\mu_j) + Tr\left(\Sigma_j^{-1} \Sigma_i\right) - D\right]
$$

**Edit:**
Because of the expansion of the Mahalanbois-looking term into a sum of bilinears:

$$
\left(\mathbf{x}_i - \mathbf{x}_j\right)^T \Sigma_j^{-1}(\mathbf{x}_I - \mathbf{x}_j) = \mathbf{x}_i^T \Sigma_j^{-1} \mathbf{x}_i - \mathbf{x}_i^T \Sigma_j^{-1} \mathbf{x}_j - \mathbf{x}_j^T \Sigma_j^{-1} \mathbf{x}_i + \mathbf{x}_j^T \Sigma_j^{-1} \mathbf{x}_j
$$

I suppose the problem can be reduced to how to efficiently compute the Gramian matrix $G_{ij}$ in the presence of a scaling matrix $\Sigma$. e.g. for the standard Gramian, where $X$ is a matrix with observations as columns,

$$X = \left( \mathbf{x}_1 \vert \mathbf{x}_2 \vert \ldots \vert \mathbf{x}_N \right)$$

$$ G = X^T X $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, if this is useful to anyone stumbling across this in the future. For the case of a diagonal covariance Gaussian, note that the Mahalanbois-looking term simplifies to:

$$
\left(\mathbf{x}_i - \mathbf{x}_j\right)^T \Sigma_j^{-1}(\mathbf{x}_I - \mathbf{x}_j) = \mathbf{x}_i^T \Sigma_j^{-1} \mathbf{x}_i - 2\mathbf{x}_i^T \Sigma_j^{-1} \mathbf{x}_j + \mathbf{x}_j^T \Sigma_j^{-1} \mathbf{x}_j
$$

It's straightforward to calculate the last two terms on the right hand side of the above equation, using the same logic as calculating the Gramian in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2240429/pairwise-distance-matrix), calculating the first term is simpler than I thought, and is clear from using the form:

$$
S_{ij} = \mathbf{x}_i^T \Sigma_j^{-1} \mathbf{x}_i = \sum_{k=1}^D \left(\sigma_j^{(k)}\right)^{-2} \left(x_i^{(k)}\right)^2
$$

To construct the matrix $S_{ij}$ in a vectorized manner, if we have a matrix holding observations as rows and a matrix where each row holds the diagonal of the covariance matrix, then we can do the following (in `torch`, but should be simple to generalize):

```
B, D = 128, 8
x, inv_var_diag = torch.randn([B,D]), torch.randn([B,D])
S_ij = x**2 @ inv_var_diag.T
```

Trying to compute this for a `(2048,2048)` matrix results in a runtime of over 10 minutes when naively iterating over each element, compared to 300 ms when computing it in vectorized form!